# does the column space of a matrix equal the column space of the reduced row echelon form of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question: does the column space of a matrix equal the column space of the reduced row echelon form of a matrix.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try with the $2$x$2$ matrix with $1$'s everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general. The first nonzero column in the reduced row echelon form is *always* the column
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and this column need not belong to the column space of the original matrix (assumed to be nonzero).

More generally, if $k$ is the rank of the matrix, the column space of the RREF is the space generated by $\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_k\}$, the first $k$ columns of the identity matrix.

So a simple example is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where the column space of $A$ is generated by $e_2$ and the column space of its RREF is generated by $e_1$.

It *can* happen that the column spaces coincide, for instance if you consider the zero matrix. But generally don't expect they do.

The *row spaces* are the same, because the rows of the RREF are linear combination of the rows of the original matrix and conversely.